# My custom locale not supported by all of its localisation delegates

Tags: flutter, dart

I created my custom locale to support my language `to`, however the App is throw the following error:

```
The following message was thrown:
Warning: This application's locale, to, is not supported by all of its localization delegates.

• A CupertinoLocalizations delegate that supports the to locale was not found.

If the application is built using GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate, consider using
GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegates (plural) instead, as that will automatically declare the
appropriate Cupertino localizations.

The declared supported locales for this app are: to, en_US

See https://flutter.dev/tutorials/internationalization/ for more information about configuring an
app's locale, supportedLocales, and localizationsDelegates parameters.
```

Inside my `main.dart` file I declare the following:

```
localizationsDelegates: const [
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            ToMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: const [Locale('to'), Locale('en', 'US')],
          locale: localeProvider.selectedLocale,
```

Here's my `to_intl.dart`

```
    import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_custom.dart' as date_symbol_data_custom;
import 'package:intl/date_symbols.dart' as intl;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl;

/// A custom set of date patterns for the `to` locale.
///
/// These are not accurate and are just a clone of the date patterns for the
/// `no` locale to demonstrate how one would write and use custom date patterns.
// #docregion Date
const toLocaleDatePatterns = {
  'd': 'd.',
  'E': 'ccc',
  'EEEE': 'cccc',
  'LLL': 'LLL',
// #enddocregion Date
  'LLLL': 'LLLL',
  'M': 'L.',
  'Md': 'd.M.',
  'MEd': 'EEE d.M.',
  'MMM': 'LLL',
  'MMMd': 'd. MMM',
  'MMMEd': 'EEE d. MMM',
  'MMMM': 'LLLL',
  'MMMMd': 'd. MMMM',
  'MMMMEEEEd': 'EEEE d. MMMM',
  'QQQ': 'QQQ',
  'QQQQ': 'QQQQ',
  'y': 'y',
  'yM': 'M.y',
  'yMd': 'd.M.y',
  'yMEd': 'EEE d.MM.y',
  'yMMM': 'MMM y',
  'yMMMd': 'd. MMM y',
  'yMMMEd': 'EEE d. MMM y',
  'yMMMM': 'MMMM y',
  'yMMMMd': 'd. MMMM y',
  'yMMMMEEEEd': 'EEEE d. MMMM y',
  'yQQQ': 'QQQ y',
  'yQQQQ': 'QQQQ y',
  'H': 'HH',
  'Hm': 'HH:mm',
  'Hms': 'HH:mm:ss',
  'j': 'HH',
  'jm': 'HH:mm',
  'jms': 'HH:mm:ss',
  'jmv': 'HH:mm v',
  'jmz': 'HH:mm z',
  'jz': 'HH z',
  'm': 'm',
  'ms': 'mm:ss',
  's': 's',
  'v': 'v',
  'z': 'z',
  'zzzz': 'zzzz',
  'ZZZZ': 'ZZZZ',
};

/// A custom set of date symbols for the `to` locale.
///
/// These are not accurate and are just a clone of the date symbols for the
/// `no` locale to demonstrate how one would write and use custom date symbols.
// #docregion Date2
const toDateSymbols = {
  'NAME': 'to',
  'ERAS': <dynamic>[
    'f.Kr.',
    'e.Kr.',
  ],
// #enddocregion Date2
  'ERANAMES': <dynamic>[
    'før Kristus',
    'etter Kristus',
  ],
  'NARROWMONTHS': <dynamic>[
    'J',
    'F',
    'M',
    'A',
    'M',
    'J',
    'J',
    'A',
    'S',
    'O',
    'N',
    'D',
  ],
  'STANDALONENARROWMONTHS': <dynamic>[
    'J',
    'F',
    'M',
    'A',
    'M',
    'J',
    'J',
    'A',
    'S',
    'O',
    'N',
    'D',
  ],
  'MONTHS': <dynamic>[
    'januar',
    'februar',
    'mars',
    'april',
    'mai',
    'juni',
    'juli',
    'august',
    'september',
    'oktober',
    'november',
    'desember',
  ],
  'STANDALONEMONTHS': <dynamic>[
    'januar',
    'februar',
    'mars',
    'april',
    'mai',
    'juni',
    'juli',
    'august',
    'september',
    'oktober',
    'november',
    'desember',
  ],
  'SHORTMONTHS': <dynamic>[
    'jan.',
    'feb.',
    'mar.',
    'apr.',
    'mai',
    'jun.',
    'jul.',
    'aug.',
    'sep.',
    'okt.',
    'nov.',
    'des.',
  ],
  'STANDALONESHORTMONTHS': <dynamic>[
    'jan',
    'feb',
    'mar',
    'apr',
    'mai',
    'jun',
    'jul',
    'aug',
    'sep',
    'okt',
    'nov',
    'des',
  ],
  'WEEKDAYS': <dynamic>[
    'søndag',
    'mandag',
    'tirsdag',
    'onsdag',
    'torsdag',
    'fredag',
    'lørdag',
  ],
  'STANDALONEWEEKDAYS': <dynamic>[
    'søndag',
    'mandag',
    'tirsdag',
    'onsdag',
    'torsdag',
    'fredag',
    'lørdag',
  ],
  'SHORTWEEKDAYS': <dynamic>[
    'søn.',
    'man.',
    'tir.',
    'ons.',
    'tor.',
    'fre.',
    'lør.',
  ],
  'STANDALONESHORTWEEKDAYS': <dynamic>[
    'søn.',
    'man.',
    'tir.',
    'ons.',
    'tor.',
    'fre.',
    'lør.',
  ],
  'NARROWWEEKDAYS': <dynamic>[
    'S',
    'M',
    'T',
    'O',
    'T',
    'F',
    'L',
  ],
  'STANDALONENARROWWEEKDAYS': <dynamic>[
    'S',
    'M',
    'T',
    'O',
    'T',
    'F',
    'L',
  ],
  'SHORTQUARTERS': <dynamic>[
    'K1',
    'K2',
    'K3',
    'K4',
  ],
  'QUARTERS': <dynamic>[
    '1. kvartal',
    '2. kvartal',
    '3. kvartal',
    '4. kvartal',
  ],
  'AMPMS': <dynamic>[
    'a.m.',
    'p.m.',
  ],
  'DATEFORMATS': <dynamic>[
    'EEEE d. MMMM y',
    'd. MMMM y',
    'd. MMM y',
    'dd.MM.y',
  ],
  'TIMEFORMATS': <dynamic>[
    'HH:mm:ss zzzz',
    'HH:mm:ss z',
    'HH:mm:ss',
    'HH:mm',
  ],
  'AVAILABLEFORMATS': null,
  'FIRSTDAYOFWEEK': 0,
  'WEEKENDRANGE': <dynamic>[
    5,
    6,
  ],
  'FIRSTWEEKCUTOFFDAY': 3,
  'DATETIMEFORMATS': <dynamic>[
    '{1} {0}',
    '{1} \'kl\'. {0}',
    '{1}, {0}',
    '{1}, {0}',
  ],
};

// #docregion Delegate
class _ToMaterialLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> {
  const _ToMaterialLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => locale.languageCode == 'to';

  @override
  Future<MaterialLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    final String localeName = intl.Intl.canonicalizedLocale(locale.toString());

    // The locale (in this case `to`) needs to be initialized into the custom
    // date symbols and patterns setup that Flutter uses.
    date_symbol_data_custom.initializeDateFormattingCustom(
      locale: localeName,
      patterns: toLocaleDatePatterns,
      symbols: intl.DateSymbols.deserializeFromMap(toDateSymbols),
    );

    return SynchronousFuture<MaterialLocalizations>(
      ToMaterialLocalizations(
        localeName: localeName,
        // The `intl` library's NumberFormat class is generated from CLDR data
        // (see https://github.com/dart-lang/i18n/blob/main/pkgs/intl/lib/number_symbols_data.dart).
        // Unfortunately, there is no way to use a locale that isn't defined in
        // this map and the only way to work around this is to use a listed
        // locale's NumberFormat symbols. So, here we use the number formats
        // for 'en_US' instead.
        decimalFormat: intl.NumberFormat('#,##0.###', 'en_US'),
        twoDigitZeroPaddedFormat: intl.NumberFormat('00', 'en_US'),
        // DateFormat here will use the symbols and patterns provided in the
        // `date_symbol_data_custom.initializeDateFormattingCustom` call above.
        // However, an alternative is to simply use a supported locale's
        // DateFormat symbols, similar to NumberFormat above.
        fullYearFormat: intl.DateFormat('y', localeName),
        compactDateFormat: intl.DateFormat('yMd', localeName),
        shortDateFormat: intl.DateFormat('yMMMd', localeName),
        mediumDateFormat: intl.DateFormat('EEE, MMM d', localeName),
        longDateFormat: intl.DateFormat('EEEE, MMMM d, y', localeName),
        yearMonthFormat: intl.DateFormat('MMMM y', localeName),
        shortMonthDayFormat: intl.DateFormat('MMM d', localeName),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(_ToMaterialLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
// #enddocregion Delegate

/// A custom set of localizations for the 'to' locale. In this example, only
/// the value for openAppDrawerTooltip was modified to use a custom message as
/// an example. Everything else uses the American English (en_US) messages
/// and formatting.
class ToMaterialLocalizations extends GlobalMaterialLocalizations {
  const ToMaterialLocalizations({
    super.localeName = 'to',
    required super.fullYearFormat,
    required super.compactDateFormat,
    required super.shortDateFormat,
    required super.mediumDateFormat,
    required super.longDateFormat,
    required super.yearMonthFormat,
    required super.shortMonthDayFormat,
    required super.decimalFormat,
    required super.twoDigitZeroPaddedFormat,
  });

// #docregion Getters
  @override
  String get moreButtonTooltip => r'More';

  @override
  String get aboutListTileTitleRaw => r'About $applicationName';

  @override
  String get alertDialogLabel => r'Alert';

// #enddocregion Getters

  @override
  String get anteMeridiemAbbreviation => r'AM';

  @override
  String get backButtonTooltip => r'Back';

  @override
  String get cancelButtonLabel => r'CANCEL';

  @override
  String get closeButtonLabel => r'CLOSE';

  @override
  String get closeButtonTooltip => r'Close';

  @override
  String get collapsedIconTapHint => r'Expand';

  @override
  String get continueButtonLabel => r'CONTINUE';

  @override
  String get copyButtonLabel => r'COPY';

  @override
  String get cutButtonLabel => r'CUT';

  @override
  String get deleteButtonTooltip => r'Delete';

  @override
  String get dialogLabel => r'Dialog';

  @override
  String get drawerLabel => r'Navigation menu';

  @override
  String get expandedIconTapHint => r'Collapse';

  @override
  String get firstPageTooltip => r'First page';

  @override
  String get hideAccountsLabel => r'Hide accounts';

  @override
  String get lastPageTooltip => r'Last page';

  @override
  String get licensesPageTitle => r'Licenses';

  @override
  String get modalBarrierDismissLabel => r'Dismiss';

  @override
  String get nextMonthTooltip => r'Next month';

  @override
  String get nextPageTooltip => r'Next page';

  @override
  String get okButtonLabel => r'OK';

  @override
  // A custom drawer tooltip message.
  String get openAppDrawerTooltip => r'Custom Navigation Menu Tooltip';

// #docregion Raw
  @override
  String get pageRowsInfoTitleRaw => r'$firstRow–$lastRow of $rowCount';

  @override
  String get pageRowsInfoTitleApproximateRaw =>
      r'$firstRow–$lastRow of about $rowCount';
// #enddocregion Raw

  @override
  String get pasteButtonLabel => r'PASTE';

  @override
  String get popupMenuLabel => r'Popup menu';

  @override
  String get menuBarMenuLabel => r'Menu Bar Label';

  @override
  String get postMeridiemAbbreviation => r'PM';

  @override
  String get previousMonthTooltip => r'Previous month';

  @override
  String get previousPageTooltip => r'Previous page';

  @override
  String get refreshIndicatorSemanticLabel => r'Refresh';

  @override
  String? get remainingTextFieldCharacterCountFew => null;

  @override
  String? get remainingTextFieldCharacterCountMany => null;

  @override
  String get remainingTextFieldCharacterCountOne => r'1 character remaining';

  @override
  String get remainingTextFieldCharacterCountOther =>
      r'$remainingCount characters remaining';

  @override
  String? get remainingTextFieldCharacterCountTwo => null;

  @override
  String get remainingTextFieldCharacterCountZero => r'No characters remaining';

  @override
  String get reorderItemDown => r'Move down';

  @override
  String get reorderItemLeft => r'Move left';

  @override
  String get reorderItemRight => r'Move right';

  @override
  String get reorderItemToEnd => r'Move to the end';

  @override
  String get reorderItemToStart => r'Move to the start';

  @override
  String get reorderItemUp => r'Move up';

  @override
  String get rowsPerPageTitle => r'Rows per page:';

  @override
  ScriptCategory get scriptCategory => ScriptCategory.englishLike;

  @override
  String get searchFieldLabel => r'Search';

  @override
  String get selectAllButtonLabel => r'SELECT ALL';

  @override
  String? get selectedRowCountTitleFew => null;

  @override
  String? get selectedRowCountTitleMany => null;

  @override
  String get selectedRowCountTitleOne => r'1 item selected';

  @override
  String get selectedRowCountTitleOther => r'$selectedRowCount items selected';

  @override
  String? get selectedRowCountTitleTwo => null;

  @override
  String get selectedRowCountTitleZero => r'No items selected';

  @override
  String get showAccountsLabel => r'Show accounts';

  @override
  String get showMenuTooltip => r'Show menu';

  @override
  String get signedInLabel => r'Signed in';

  @override
  String get tabLabelRaw => r'Tab $tabIndex of $tabCount';

  @override
  TimeOfDayFormat get timeOfDayFormatRaw => TimeOfDayFormat.h_colon_mm_space_a;

  @override
  String get timePickerHourModeAnnouncement => r'Select hours';

  @override
  String get timePickerMinuteModeAnnouncement => r'Select minutes';

  @override
  String get viewLicensesButtonLabel => r'VIEW LICENSES';

  @override
  List<String> get narrowWeekdays =>
      const <String>['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'];

  @override
  int get firstDayOfWeekIndex => 0;

  static const LocalizationsDelegate<MaterialLocalizations> delegate =
      _ToMaterialLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  String get calendarModeButtonLabel => r'Switch to calendar';

  @override
  String get dateHelpText => r'mm/dd/yyyy';

  @override
  String get dateInputLabel => r'Enter Date';

  @override
  String get dateOutOfRangeLabel => r'Out of range.';

  @override
  String get datePickerHelpText => r'SELECT DATE';

  @override
  String get dateRangeEndDateSemanticLabelRaw => r'End date $fullDate';

  @override
  String get dateRangeEndLabel => r'End Date';

  @override
  String get dateRangePickerHelpText => 'SELECT RANGE';

  @override
  String get dateRangeStartDateSemanticLabelRaw => 'Start date \$fullDate';

  @override
  String get dateRangeStartLabel => 'Start Date';

  @override
  String get dateSeparator => '/';

  @override
  String get dialModeButtonLabel => 'Switch to dial picker mode';

  @override
  String get inputDateModeButtonLabel => 'Switch to input';

  @override
  String get inputTimeModeButtonLabel => 'Switch to text input mode';

  @override
  String get invalidDateFormatLabel => 'Invalid format.';

  @override
  String get invalidDateRangeLabel => 'Invalid range.';

  @override
  String get invalidTimeLabel => 'Enter a valid time';

  @override
  String get licensesPackageDetailTextOther => '\$licenseCount licenses';

  @override
  String get saveButtonLabel => 'SAVE';

  @override
  String get selectYearSemanticsLabel => 'Select year';

  @override
  String get timePickerDialHelpText => 'SELECT TIME';

  @override
  String get timePickerHourLabel => 'Hour';

  @override
  String get timePickerInputHelpText => 'ENTER TIME';

  @override
  String get timePickerMinuteLabel => 'Minute';

  @override
  String get unspecifiedDate => 'Date';

  @override
  String get unspecifiedDateRange => 'Date Range';

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyAlt => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyAltGraph => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyBackspace => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyCapsLock => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyChannelDown => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyChannelUp => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyControl => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyDelete => throw UnimplementedError();

  String get keyboardKeyEisu => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyEject => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyEnd => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyEscape => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyFn => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyHome => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyInsert => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyMeta => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyMetaMacOs => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyMetaWindows => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumLock => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpad0 => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpad1 => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpad2 => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpad3 => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpad4 => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpad5 => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpad6 => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpad7 => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpad8 => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpad9 => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpadAdd => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpadComma => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpadDecimal => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpadDivide => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpadEnter => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpadEqual => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpadMultiply => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpadParenLeft => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpadParenRight => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyNumpadSubtract => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyPageDown => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyPageUp => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyPower => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyPowerOff => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyPrintScreen => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeyScrollLock => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeySelect => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  String get keyboardKeySpace => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  get scrimOnTapHintRaw => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  get bottomSheetLabel => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  get currentDateLabel => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  get keyboardKeyShift => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  get scrimLabel => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  get collapsedHint => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  get expandedHint => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  get expansionTileCollapsedHint => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  get expansionTileCollapsedTapHint => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  get expansionTileExpandedHint => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  get expansionTileExpandedTapHint => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  get scanTextButtonLabel => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the Warning message says GlobalCupertinoLocalizations does not support Locale('to'). Look here for a list of supported locales: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/GlobalCupertinoLocalizations-class.html

Flutter is providing some translations for certain Locales out-of-the-box. For example the calendar widget has been translated into several languages by the flutter team. This means us programmers can use these widgets in several locales without having to translate them ourselves.
Using GlobalCupertinoLocalizations delegate means you want to make use of the flutter translated iOS widgets. However, this is not possible for you as flutter has not translated the iOS widgets to Locale('to').
You can

1. either forgo the use of flutters out-of-the-box translations (i.e. do not add GlobalCupertinoLocalizations delegate to your list of delegates)
2. ignore the error and accept that some iOS widgets will default to en_US
3. define your own translations for the iOS widgets: Have a look at https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization under "Adding support for a new language"